# Moment of inertia of 2d domain with boundary given by point representation

Tags: matlab

I found that for 2d integration I need function handles for the boundary. How can I do that if I have only point representation of the boundary?

Comment: Think of your boundary as a polygon then apply [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Any_cross_section_defined_as_polygon).

Comment: @denahiro why not turn that into an anwer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

You can think of your point boundary as the points of a polygon and apply [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Any_cross_section_defined_as_polygon). Note that the points need to be ordered in clock-wise order otherwise you get negative values.